# ACF repeater - if subfield has a value in ANY of the rows : do something

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I found a solution to my problem, but it's a "hack". I'm learning PHP and I would like to know how I should have proceeded.

I have a repeater, and inside this repeater a true/false to activate options for each row.
I want to display a "Options header" only if ANY of the rows have this true/false on TRUE.
So, I did the following:

```
<?php $rows = get_field('mytable');
if( $rows ) { 

$optionsonoff = $row['displayoptions']; /* my true/false button */

if ( $optionsonoff ) { ?>

<tr><td>OPTIONS</td></tr>

<?php }} ?>
```

This almost works. Almost, because somehow it doesn't take into account the first row, so if the first row has the true/false on true and all the other rows on false it won't work.

So, I added a second variable to specifically get the value of that true false in the first row, and added it to my IF statement:

```
$optionsonoff = $row['displayoptions'];
$optionsonofffirstrow = $rows[0]['displayoptions'];

if ( $optionsonoff OR $optionsonofffirstrow ) { ... } ?>
```

This works, but I would like to understand:

- Why the first row wasn't counted in my first variable (maybe something specific to ACF?)
- More than anything, I would like to learn the correct / simplest way to achieve what I wanted ? Something with while(rows) or if(have_rows) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but if you have to loop the command is the_repeater_field.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_repeater_field/

Is that what you needed?